# Input JSON on web-api POST (C#)

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I currently have my web API binded to my computer files, like this:

```
namespace APIDissertação.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DissertacaoController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(/*JObject InputRequest*/)
        {
            try
            {
                DissertacaoClass MeuProblema = new DissertacaoClass();
                MeuProblema.ArquivoGrafo_InicializarProblema(@"C:\C#\ArquivoGrafo.txt");
                MeuProblema.ArquivoNv0(@"C:\C#\ArquivoNv0.txt");
                MeuProblema.LerArquivoDemandas(@"C:\C#\ArquivoDemandas.txt");
                MeuProblema.GerarCaminhos_Arcos();
                String result = MeuProblema.CriarResolverProblema();
                return Ok(result);//ResultRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

What I want to do, is to substitute this file to a JSON that will be inputed to the API, the JSON would look like this:

```
{
 "QuantidadeNosSemTempo": 4
 "QuantidadeTempos": 12
 "Grafo_Terminal;X;Y;Nv0": [
  "0;0;0;1", 
  "1;2;2;1", 
  "2;3;1;1", 
  "3;0;3;1" 
 ],
 "Demanda;TerminalNoInicial;TempoNoInicial;TerminalNoFinal;TempoNoFinal;Tamanho" : [
  "0;0;0;2;8;0,7",
  "1;0;0;3;11;0,3",
  "2;1;0;2;8;0,5",
  "3;1;1;2;9;0,5",
  "4;2;1;0;10;0,3",
  "5;2;1;3;11;0,2"
 ]
}
```

How can I do that?
I'm pretty new in web api development (actually have no idea what I'm doing),

Thanks in advance,

Tarek

Answer (score 0):

You can use type dynamic if you want all structures to be accepted.

However I prefer to generate a type using a tool like https://app.quicktype.io/ and use that DTO afterwards.

Also your json structure had an issue with some missing commas

```json
{
 "QuantidadeNosSemTempo": 4,
 "QuantidadeTempos": 12,
 "Grafo_Terminal;X;Y;Nv0": [
  "0;0;0;1", 
  "1;2;2;1", 
  "2;3;1;1", 
  "3;0;3;1" 
 ],
 "Demanda;TerminalNoInicial;TempoNoInicial;TerminalNoFinal;TempoNoFinal;Tamanho" : [
  "0;0;0;2;8;0,7",
  "1;0;0;3;11;0,3",
  "2;1;0;2;8;0,5",
  "3;1;1;2;9;0,5",
  "4;2;1;0;10;0,3",
  "5;2;1;3;11;0,2"
 ]
}
```

After that you simply send a http POST request with content type "application/json" and where  the body of the request contains the json to that url and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just as suggestion, maybe you could change your json a litle bit, like this (note that I change the two arrays in your json by `FirstArray` and `SecondArray`):

```
{
"QuantidadeNosSemTempo": 4,
"QuantidadeTempos": 12,
"FirstArray": [{
        "Grafo_Terminal": 0,
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Nv0": 1
    }, {
        "Grafo_Terminal": 1,
        "X": 2,
        "Y": 2,
        "Nv0": 1
    }, {
        "Grafo_Terminal": 2,
        "X": 3,
        "Y": 1,
        "Nv0": 1
    }, {
        "Grafo_Terminal": 3,
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 3,
        "Nv0": 1
    }
],
"SecondArray": [{
        "Demanda": 0,
        "TerminalNoInicial": 0,
        "TempoNoInicial": 0,
        "TerminalNoFinal": 2,
        "TempoNoFinal": 8,
        "Tamanho": 0.7
    }, {
        "Demanda": 1,
        "TerminalNoInicial": 0,
        "TempoNoInicial": 0,
        "TerminalNoFinal": 3,
        "TempoNoFinal": 11,
        "Tamanho": 0.3
    }, {
        "Demanda": 2,
        "TerminalNoInicial": 1,
        "TempoNoInicial": 0,
        "TerminalNoFinal": 2,
        "TempoNoFinal": 8,
        "Tamanho": 0.5
    }, {
        "Demanda": 3,
        "TerminalNoInicial": 1,
        "TempoNoInicial": 1,
        "TerminalNoFinal": 2,
        "TempoNoFinal": 9,
        "Tamanho": 0.5
    }, {
        "Demanda": 4,
        "TerminalNoInicial": 2,
        "TempoNoInicial": 1,
        "TerminalNoFinal": 0,
        "TempoNoFinal": 10,
        "Tamanho": 0.3
    }, {
        "Demanda": 5,
        "TerminalNoInicial": 2,
        "TempoNoInicial": 1,
        "TerminalNoFinal": 3,
        "TempoNoFinal": 11,
        "Tamanho": 0.2
    }
]
```

}

And your C# class that will be the input request could be a DTO (`InputRequest`):

```
    public class FirstArray    {
        public int Grafo_Terminal { get; set; } 
        public int X { get; set; } 
        public int Y { get; set; } 
        public int Nv0 { get; set; } 
    }

    public class SecondArray    {
        public int Demanda { get; set; } 
        public int TerminalNoInicial { get; set; } 
        public int TempoNoInicial { get; set; } 
        public int TerminalNoFinal { get; set; } 
        public int TempoNoFinal { get; set; } 
        public double Tamanho { get; set; } 
    }

    public class InputRequest    {
        public int QuantidadeNosSemTempo { get; set; } 
        public int QuantidadeTempos { get; set; } 
        public List<FirstArray> FirstArray { get; set; } 
        public List<SecondArray> SecondArray { get; set; } 
    }
```

So, if you implement this changes, your post method will be:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(InputRequest inputRequest)
{
    try
    {
        DissertacaoClass MeuProblema = new DissertacaoClass();
        String result = MeuProblema.CriarResolverProblema(inputRequest); //you will have to change the way you resolve the problem
        return Ok(result); //ResultRequest
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```